# T-SQL MERGE with condition what is not matched?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I made a merge matched with a condition like

```
MERGE TargetTable WITH(HOLDLOCK) AS target
USING SourceTable AS source
ON (target.ID = source.ID)
WHEN MATCHED AND (source.BitCondition = 0) THEN
    UPDATE TargetTable
WHEN NOT MATCHED -- what is not matched??
    INSERT INTO TargetTable
```

Is the not matched just records not in both tables or is it like

```
NOT(MATCHED AND (source.BitCondition = 0))
```

**N.B. I intentionally want to ignore the case where it's matched and BitCondition = 1**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default for `NOT MATCHED` according to the [MERGE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) is `NOT MATCHED BY TARGET`, meaning the row exists in the source but not the target of the `MERGE`.

To avoid inserting unmatched rows with `source.BitCondition = 1`, you can add an `AND` condition:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND (source.BitCondition = 0) THEN
    INSERT INTO TargetTable
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Dan. Just what I needed :D

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, it's "just records not in both tables". More technically, `NOT MATCHED` evaluated using only the condition defined in the `ON <merge_search_condition>` clause.

In other words, you may consider `MATCHED` as an alias for the `<merge_search_condition>`.

So your query may be written (in pseudo code) as

```
MERGE ...
ON (target.ID = source.ID)
WHEN (target.ID = source.ID) AND (source.BitCondition = 0) THEN
    UPDATE TargetTable
WHEN NOT (target.ID = source.ID) 
    INSERT INTO TargetTable
```